# Trouble inserting newline in String^

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Prof for a Windows Forms Application.
When I have a String^ and insert characters in it, it works like a charm. If I want to insert a newline ("\n") and print it into a multi-line Box, the newline is not visible.

If I move through the output with my cursor however, it acts as if two invisible characters are in the position where I inserted the newline. It definitely inserted something, but it's either rubbish or my IDE is incorrectly configured.

```
textB = textB->Insert(CoordStart+5,"\n");
```

Where CoordStart is the index.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
textB = textB->Insert(CoordStart+5,"\n");
```

To:

```
textB = textB->Insert(CoordStart+5,"\r\n");
```